# Change labels of Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to change Google spreadsheet header labels. I would like to change A,B,C... to more detailed descriptions. How do I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Those are not header labels. Those are the names of the columns. You can add your own text in Row A if you wish.

Comment: But how to add text instead of A? It is not editable in my spreadsheet

Comment: Add it in Cell A1. The cells themselves are editable. You can then format it to look like a column header and to scroll. It's like calling Room A112 in an office the 'supply room'. You can add a name to a column yourself but you can't change the actual identify of the column.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. This is not how spreadsheets operate. The best you can have is the top row containing column names. Then you can freeze it, filter it etc.